# Simple BigQuery LEFT JOIN doesn't retain rows on left

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a very simple query that's not bringing back what I expect.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  P.name AS `plantName`,
  P.sku AS `plantSku`,
FROM
  `wow-plants-for-sale.ds1.Plants` AS P
JOIN
  `wow-plants-for-sale.ds1.PlantDescriptions` AS D ON P.sku = D.sku
LEFT JOIN 
  `wow-plants-for-sale.ds1.LineItems` AS Lines ON D.sku = Lines.sku
WHERE
  DATE(Lines._PARTITIONTIME) >= "2023-02-01"
  AND DATE(P._PARTITIONTIME) >= "2023-02-01"
  AND DATE(D._PARTITIONTIME) >= "2023-02-01"
```

- I have three different plant SKUs in my fake shop, each with a description, and there are customer invoices (LineItems) for two of these plants.
- I want a row for each of the three plants and its invoice data, but a bunch of nulls/missing data for the plant with no invoice data.
- What I get is just two rows; one for each that has a "line item".
- When I remove my `LEFT JOIN` I get three rows, for each of my plants.
- My understanding is that the left-hand data, plants, should be retained.

**Note** - I've reduced the `SELECT` down to just two columns for troubleshooting.

**Note** - I have configured partitioning by month with forced `WHERE` clause enabled.

##### Have Tried

```sql
...
WHERE
  (Lines._PARTITIONTIME IS NULL OR DATE(Lines._PARTITIONTIME) >= "2023-02-01")
  AND DATE(P._PARTITIONTIME) >= "2023-02-01"
  AND DATE(D._PARTITIONTIME) >= "2023-02-01"
```

But that gives:

> Cannot query over table 'blah.blah.LineItems' without a filter over column(s) '_PARTITION_LOAD_TIME', '_PARTITIONTIME' that can be used for partition elimination

I wonder whether the configuration to force partition queries was a bad idea.

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` will retain the rows, but all the columns in `Lines.*` will be `null` if there was no match so your `WHERE` condition will fail. You likely want to handle that (e.g. `WHERE (Lines._PARTITIONTIME IS NULL OR DATE(Lines._PARTITIONTIME) >= "2023-02-01") ...`)

Comment: Interestingly that gives "Cannot query over table 'blah.blah.LineItems' without a filter over column(s) '_PARTITION_LOAD_TIME', '_PARTITIONTIME' that can be used for partition elimination"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```sql
LEFT JOIN 
  `wow-plants-for-sale.ds1.LineItems` AS Lines ON D.sku = Lines.sku AND DATE(Lines._PARTITIONTIME) >= "2023-02-01"
WHERE
  DATE(P._PARTITIONTIME) >= "2023-02-01"
  AND DATE(D._PARTITIONTIME) >= "2023-02-01"
```

Thanks to EdmCoff for pointing me in the right direction.